# What is difference between TridentTopologies and storm topologies?

Tags: apache-storm

I am not getting the good difference between trident topologies and storm topologies,while creating spout i am using  BaseRichspout .I am using trident topologies object while creating topologies and its working

So ,some one help me to know a good difference between them

Answer (score 1):

Trident is an abstraction on top of Storm to provide exactly once processing. Storm uses Spouts, Bolts, and Sinks.  Trident uses Functions, Filters, and States and transforms these into Bolts. If you're not sure you need Trident, I'd suggest you use Storm and not mix the two.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, is TridentTopology is helpful for machine learning?

Comment: Maybe. I think it would depend on what you wanted to do.  There is a ML library for Trident : https://github.com/pmerienne/trident-ml